# Custom pop-up for multiple results in ArcGIS Online application

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, popup

I have a point layer that contains business locations where the businesses offer services from different providers. i.e. competing businesses.

A customer is requesting a modified pop-up to display, as to not imply that one service is "better" than another. Gotta make the customer, as well as the competing businesses happy, right??

Rather than having a pop-up display (1 of 2) and (2 of 2) is there a way to:

A. Create a blank pop up first, preferably with some sort of index or key that says something to the effect of "There are 2 providers at this location, scroll right to see providers"?

**or**

B. Have all pop-ups display at once in separate panes (some kind of multi pop-up) displaying all info at once. Or alternatively, have one large popup pane that displays all location information at once.
[image: same location, different item sold]
[image: same location, different item sold]

**Preference B. would be best and likely the easiest, I would imagine. Any tricks, tips or hacks are welcome.**

Comment: You added the javascript-api tag, does that mean this is a custom javascript application, or are you just using the default viewers as part of arcgis online?

Comment: You could think about combining the data using featuresets https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/mapping/mapping/whats-new-with-arcade-taking-a-stroll-through-featuresets-part-1/

Comment: KHibma - This is a default template for an ArcGIS online application. I added the tag so it would reach more people. I've never created a thread before here in Stack Exchange so I am not sure if that was a correct tag to add. I feel like I will need some custom coding to create this solution so I wanted to reach those folks. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For option A, you can use Web AppBuilder Developer to configure the popup window. Once you download, the file you want to modify is can be found here:

\client\stemapp\widgets\PopupPanel\Widget.js

In the file, the header for the popup window will be around line 205. You'll want to change:

```
this.featureCount.innerHTML = "(1 of " + this.popup.features.length + ")";
```

to

```
this.featureCount.innerHTML = "(There are/is " + this.popup.features.length + "Provider at this location.";
```

Comment: I've downloaded the Web AppBuilder Developer but this is new territory for me. I will look into it more and try your code. Any ideas on how to achieve option B, where all pop-ups display at once?